# Calculate how many days are required for a snail to climb up a wall

Tags: c++

I am trying to solve this problem:

> Write a program to calculate how many days are required for a snail to climb up a wall. A snail climbs on a wall, it starts at the bottom and climbs up *n* meters a day. Regretfully, every night it slides *m* meters down. Given the height of the wall *H*, write a program to calculate how many days required for the snail to reach the top of the wall.
> If the snail will never be able to reach the top of the wall print: Fail.

This is my attempt to solve this problem:

```
int numDays(int wall_height, int meters_per_day, int meters_down_per_day) {
    int current_height = 0;
    int days = 0;

    while (current_height != wall_height) {
        if (current_height + (meters_per_day - meters_down_per_day) >= wall_height) {
            break;
        }else {
            days += 1;
            current_height += meters_per_day - meters_down_per_day;
        }
    }

    return days;
}

int main()
{
    int wall_height = 30;
    int meters_per_day = 3;
    int meters_down = 2;

    if (meters_down >= meters_per_day) {
        cout << "Fail" << endl;
    }else {
        cout << numDays(wall_height, meters_per_day, meters_down) << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

My solution returns 29 days, but the answer is 28 days because once the snail has climbed 27 meters after 27 days, it will simply climb the remaining 3 meters to the top on the 28th day.

What I am doing wrong to generate the wrong output? Thanks!

Comment: You don't need a `while` loop to solve this, btw.

Comment: I'm sure this is an off by one error, but this is not a code review site. Try using very small numbers, calculate it by hand, and confirm that your code gives the right answer.

Comment: Like @Dai mentioned, you shouldn't actually need a while loop for this, but it seems you're likely a newer programmer, so just get the job done however it makes sense in your head for now. Clean up later. As for your mistake, check the if statement on line 6. You're sliding down too soon. If `current_height + meters_per_day` gets you to the top before night, you're done. ONLY if night comes, do you slide down.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your error is that you are only checking if the snail has reached the top of the wall after it has climbed up and down. You even say this yourself. Instead you should check the height after the climb up only

Here's loop that does that.

```
for (;;) {
    current_height += meters_per_day;
    if (current_height >= wall_height) {
        break;
    current_height -= meters_down_per_day;
    days += 1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For me, here is the right implementation of your `numDays` function :

```cpp
int numDays(int wall_height, int meters_per_day, int meters_down_per_day) {
    int current_height = 0;
    int days = 1;

    while (current_height != wall_height) {
        current_height += meters_per_day;
        
        if(current_height >= wall_height)
            break;
        
        days += 1;
        current_height -= meters_down_per_day;
    }

    return days;
}
```

> the answer is 28 days because once the snail has climbed 27 meters after 27 days, it will simply climb the remaining 3 meters to the top on the 28th day

To do this, you need to increment first the `current_height` before testing if the snail is on the top of the wall.

I think the day counter must start at 1 because the first day of iteration is the day 1 (I don't know if the explanation is really clear).

Answer (score 0):

Here's my simple Python program to solve the problem that implements the given conditions:

```
def num_days(h, n, m):
    days = 0
    position = 0
    while n < h:
        if m >= n:
            break
        days += 1
        position += n
        if position >= h:
            return days
        position -= m
    if days == 0:
        days = 'Fail'
    return days
```

You can call the function `num_days` with h, n, and m as arguments to get the number of days required for the snail to reach the top of the wall.

For example:
`num_days(11, 3, 2)`
return
`9`

`num_days(5, 3, 1)`
return
`2`

`num_days(5, 0, 1)`
return
`Fail`